# AJAX is working on second click only

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my `index.html` page where am trying to implement a simple AJAX when clicked on anchor tag the text will be passed to PHP `data.php` page and that page will display the page being clicked. Yes, the code is working, but when I first click on the link nothing is displayed and from the second time it stars working. Where is the problem actually?

This is my script

```
<script>
$(document).click(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        //when clicked our ajax will work
        $.get('data.php',{'page':$(this).text()},function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is my PHP for the AJAX

```
<?php    
$anchortext=$_GET['page'];
if(isset($anchortext))
{
    echo 'this is a'.$anchortext;
}   
?>
```

Comment: Use $(document).ready(function() {
});

Answer (score 6):

You misplaced `$(document).click(..)` for `$(document).ready(....)`, so only after the first click the click handler is registered to the `a` element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        //when clicked our ajax will work
        $.get('data.php',{'page':$(this).text()},function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).ready` instead of `$(document).click`.

Comment: This was probably downvoted as it is very brief, and would probably have been better as a comment. If you write longer answers you should be fine. Incidentally, if you wrap text in backticks then you'll get `inline code formatting`, which is better for code.

Comment: Thanks @halfer i have changes my code but before i got downvote. Thanks for support.